# SnowFlake/SQL - Filtering for Weeks 50,51 and 52 of 2023 + week 1 of 2024

Tags: sql, datefilter

I am trying to filter for the previous four weeks.
But I do get broken weeks with the change of the year from 2023 and 2024

I have tried a lot of queries, but it is only complicating my query more. Maybe we can try and add a row_number to rearrange the weeks so we do not break the year to year change.

This is my query:

```
QUALIFY MIN(to_decimal(year(date(ETA_PUBLISHED))||weekiso(date(ETA_PUBLISHED)))) OVER (PARTITION BY VOYAGE_REF) 
        BETWEEN to_decimal(year(sysdate())||weekiso(sysdate())) -4 AND
                to_decimal(year(sysdate())||weekiso(sysdate())) -1
```

This has caused an issue on the shift from 2023-2024, where the condition above is no longer abided.
Example:

```
20241 (Current Week)

202352(Week Before)

202351(2 Weeks Before)

202350(3 weeks before)
```

...

My issue lies here, how can I filter for the previous 4 weeks without broken weeks, or without hard coding my query.

I am aware the concatenation is my biggest problem but  I cant figure out a better way to think about it

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Also add some sample table data and the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. provide a complete [mcve] - make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Sounds like the need for a calendar table, or the use of ISO Weeks.

Comment: As long as you order by year and week, what's the issue? As others have said, please update your question with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve

Comment: @NickW are you able to help now that this is updated?

Comment: @OdetteDeeba please update your question with your full SQL statement (or at least a minimal reproducible example) - rather than just the QUALIFY clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
QUALIFY MIN(ETA_PUBLISHED) OVER (PARTITION BY VOYAGE_REF) BETWEEN
        trunc(sysdate() - interval '3 week', 'week')             -- 2023-12-11 00:00:00.000
    AND dateadd(second, 24*60*60-1, last_day(sysdate(), 'week')) -- 2024-01-07 23:59:59.000
```